# Cygwin console jabber client

Tags: cygwin, xmpp

Do there exist any cygwin console jabber clients?  I've not successfully compiled any of the console clients [listed here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) in cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Profanity?

http://www.profanity.im/

It works on Cygwin, includes desktop notifications on Windows, and the download has a script to install Cygwin dependencies for compile.